# Indexing zip files with Lucene

Tags: java, lucene

Is it possible to index zipped folders in lucene. If i unzip it the content is too large.
If i just index the bunch of zipped folders containing textfiles,
The serach does not work properly.
Is it possible for lucene to index with out extracting the zip file.

Comment: Short answer: Yes. Long answer: We'll need more details (e.g. [what have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)) if you want a better answer.

Comment: to index the folders containing text files.if i zip the folders and index it search does not work.But if unzip and index it ,search works properly. The input to the indexer is the folder containing all the folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lucene is just a search library and there's no way it can "know" every possible scenario - e.g. how to index XML documents, word files, files inside .zip, files created by Chernobyl power plant, etc.

But what Lucene does it to provide [the API](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_1_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/standard/StandardAnalyzer.html) for you to hook your data into Lucene.

If unzipping the contents of the archive file is not an option, you could write a class that [reads the zip file](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipInputStream.html) (but does not unzip it on the disk) and feeds this data into Lucene.

If your primary concern is the size of the index, there's nothing much you can do to reduce it. There are a few tips though:

- try indexing without stopwords
- do not store the fields, only index them (hint: [Field.Store.NO](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_1_0/core/org/apache/lucene/document/Field.Store.html))
- always lowercase all terms to reduce term count

Comment: My point was to reduce the size of the index.This will still increase the size of the index.

Comment: I don't think I get your point. If you don't want to index the data which is inside .zip files, what problem exactly are you facing?

Comment: The size of the index will be large if i unzip and feed the file to lucene. Can i  do anything to reduce the size of the index.

Comment: That sounds good. can you help me with the code to unzip the file without putting it on disk.

Comment: What in particular are you having problems with? [This article](http://www.javaworld.com/community/node/8362) has got some examples on how to read and write a file from/to a .zip.